# Add same value in multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, push

I need to push the same value into array of arrays.

```
values.map(function(){
   for (i=0; i<= values.length; i++){
      values[i].push('AdWords');
   } 
});
```

The problem is that push 2 times the same value only in 1 array

```
[
 [
  "2018-06-06",
  "Services",
  "65",
  "1",
  "4690000",
  "4690000",
  "1.54%",
  "AdWords",
  "AdWords"
 ],
 [
  "2018-06-06",
  "Services",
  "65",
  "1",
  "4690000",
  "4690000",
  "1.54%"     
 ]
]
```

Comment: Do you want to push `AdWords` at the end of each array once or multiple times for every array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to change the array, you should use `forEach` instead of `map`

```js
let values = [
  ["2018-06-06","Services","65","1","4690000","4690000","1.54%",],
  ["2018-06-06","Services","65","1","4690000","4690000","1.54%"]
];

values.forEach(function(o) {
  o.push('AdWords');
});

console.log(values);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
for (i=0; i< values.length; i++){
  values[i].push('AdWords');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `for loop` for this operation.

**Working Example:**

```js
/* VALUES ARRAY */

var values = [
  [
  "2018-06-06",
  "Services",
  "65",
  "1",
  "4690000",
  "4690000",
  "1.54%"
 ],

 [
  "2018-06-06",
  "Services",
  "65",
  "1",
  "4690000",
  "4690000",
  "1.54%"     
 ]
];



/* OPERATION */

for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {

    values[i].push('AdWords');
};



/* RESULT */

console.log(values);
```

---

**N.B.** Note the use of `let` to declare the loop iterator variable `i`.

> `let` allows you to declare variables that are limited in scope to the
>   block, statement, or expression on which it is used.

**Source:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

Answer (score 0):

You might use `for...of` statement if you may use ES6

```js
var values = [
  [
    "2018-06-06",
    "Services",
    "65",
    "1",
    "4690000",
    "4690000",
    "1.54%"
  ],
  [
    "2018-06-06",
    "Services",
    "65",
    "1",
    "4690000",
    "4690000",
    "1.54%"
  ]
];


for (let val of values) {
  val.push('AdWords');
};

console.log(values);
```